# Prometheus добавление метрик

Tags: linux, docker, docker-compose, devops, prometheus

Как в Prometheus ( через pushgateway) добавить свои метрики? Вся система развернута на докер контейнерах.

Answer (score 0):

Вообще у Prometheus pull модель, т.е. он сам должен ходить и собирать метрики.

Если вы хотите использовать pushgateway, возможно вам он не подходит.

---

Похожее [решение](https://habr.com/ru/post/531500/).

Comment: Хотя по ссылке можно найти ответ на вопрос, лучше указать здесь самое главное, а ссылку приводить в качестве источника.  Если страница, на которую ведет ссылка, будет изменена, ответ-ссылка может стать недействительным. — [из очереди проверок](/review/late-answers/782712)